# how can i correct atmospherically landsat 8 images?

Tags: grass-gis, remote-sensing, landsat-8

I am trying to correct atmospherically an image from Landsat 8 with 6s model from grass 7 and 6.4. Because there are no parameters for Landsat 8 yet, I am trying to give parameters from Landsat 7 images. When I use `i.atcorr` I get this message:

```
wavelength  less  than  0.25  micron: 
 let's take s(l)=s(0.25)
```

and the command ends.

How can I correct my Landsat 8 images? Is there someone who knows when Landsat 8 images will officially be in 6s model?

Comment: This may help  http://www.gisagmaps.com/landsat-8-data-tutorial/ , a stop gap perhaps. It has the attraction of being able to be completed in QGIS, but is very sensitive to the selection of the haze parameters.

Comment: @Willy the website requires a paid login. Would be useful to post links that are accessible to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You couldn't expect the `i.atcorr` module to work for Landsat8 imagery, while instructing it to use parameters for Landsat7 acquisitions. Completely different data (both in terms of the sensors radiometric capabilities and the bitness of the delivered products -- 8-bit vs. 16-bit).

However, there is now support for Landsat8 imagery in [`i.atcorr`](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/i.atcorr.html) (GRASS GIS ver. 7.x). Also, a custom python script, named [`i.landsat.atcorr`](https://github.com/NikosAlexandris/i.landsat.atcorr), attempts to make things easier.